# Avoiding using loops on large dataset in R while adding a second onto repeat data

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

I'm working on reformatting a large set of water quality data in order to feed back into a database. When the volunteers take the data, they'll often use a sample of water for multiple tests and record it as the same sample number,date, and time. However, the database won't accept this and needs the sample time to be different. The solution to this is historically has been to add a second on to each subsequent measurement for the same sample number. For example,

```
Sample Number                DateTime
 180433               2019-11-04 12:30:00
 180433               2019-11-04 12:30:00
 180433               2019-11-04 12:30:00
 180433               2019-11-04 12:30:00
 180433               2019-11-04 12:30:00
```

then I would need the times to be 12:30:00, 12:30:01, 12:30:02, 12:30:03, 12:30:04. While I have written some code for this, it's a little clunky and I know there has to be a more elegant method.

```
LIMS_dup<-LIMS_data[duplicated(LIMS_data[,c(4,8:9)]),c(4,8:9)]

x<-NA
for (i in 1:length(unique(LIMS_dup$CustomerSampleNumber))){
  x<-which(as.integer(LIMS_data$CustomerSampleNumber)==as.integer(unique(LIMS_dup$CustomerSampleNumber)[i]))
  if (length(x)>1){
    for (j in 2:length(x)){
      LIMS_data$CollectTime[x[j]]<-LIMS_data$CollectTime[x[j-1]]+1
    }
  }
}
```

Where LIMS_data is my main tibble and LIMS_dup is a tibble of the duplicate sample numbers and times. This does work, but it's a little slow. I was hoping to find a better method, particularly one that doesn't rely on nested loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `ave` for sequential count by group (here being sample number) to be add to a `POSIXct` datetime type (i.e., adds seconds):

```
df$New_DateTime <- with(df, DateTime + (ave(as.numeric(DateTime), Sample_Number, FUN=seq_along)-1))

df
#   Sample_Number            DateTime        New_DateTime
# 1        180433 2019-11-04 12:30:00 2019-11-04 12:30:00
# 2        180433 2019-11-04 12:30:00 2019-11-04 12:30:01
# 3        180433 2019-11-04 12:30:00 2019-11-04 12:30:02
# 4        180433 2019-11-04 12:30:00 2019-11-04 12:30:03
# 5        180433 2019-11-04 12:30:00 2019-11-04 12:30:04
```

<kbd>[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/QPTX56951)</kbd>